# OpenIddict doesn't support localization

Tags: abp

I found the ABP's OpenIddict doesn't support localization currently, I looked at the history of PR and found there is PR to remove the localization early.

https://github.com/abpframework/abp/commit/6953e9c8a400925a4c9ef0e823ff3d645856c1dd#diff-dba639ee7aaba84fa06dcba562eb566059e2c1f86cb76481a2d8566fa88f186e

Why localization is removed from the OpenIddict module?

How to override default message?

Comment: Related github issue: https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/15398

Answer (score 2):

> Why localization is removed from the OpenIddict module?

That's because the OAuth 2.0 specification restricts the charset you're allowed to use for the `error` and `error_description` parameters:

> A.7.  "error" Syntax
>
> The "error" element is defined in Sections 4.1.2.1, 4.2.2.1, 5.2,
> 7.2, and 8.5:
>
> ```
>  error             = 1*NQSCHAR
> ```
>
> A.8.  "error_description" Syntax
>
> The "error_description" element is defined in Sections 4.1.2.1,
> 4.2.2.1, 5.2, and 7.2:
>
> ```
>  error-description = 1*NQSCHAR
> ```

> ```
>  NQSCHAR    = %x20-21 / %x23-5B / %x5D-7E
> ```

In practice, being able to only use a subset of US-ASCII prevents you from returning localized messages (even simple diacritics like `é` or `à` - that are common in French - are illegal) and that's why the ABP team decided to remove them: not doing so would have made their OpenID Connect implementation non-standard.